# financial transactions with and without commissions

Tags: database-design

I'm building a gambling website. All financial transactions from and to external sources (credit cards,  money transfer systems) are subject to commission. Amount of the commission depends on the source selected. And moreover, it changes periodically. These external commissions go to the payment systems.

Also some inner transactions are subject to commission. Inner commissions depend on the type of the game user playing. These internal commissions go to gambling website, it is the income.

I'm looking for the best way to store the history of transactions and commissions. Should they be stored in one table TRANSACTIONS (with a connection between payment and commission) or should I have separate table COMMISSIONS.

The purpose of storing is to represent the history of transactions to the user and of course for internal bookkeeping (in order to always know how much have we paid to payment systems and how much have we earned ourselves).

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you store the commission *rate* in its own table but store the commission *amount* in the transactions table that may work nicely.

Comment: 2JNK: Yeah, this is what I'm going to do. But willn't it pollute TRANSACTIONS table with redundant fields? For example in transaction which represents the commission I need to keep a key of the commission rate applied. But in all other types of transactions this field will be NULL.

Comment: That's why we have `NULL`!  I think it's fine but I'm not confident enough to post it as an answer, notice :)

Comment: The truth is I probably also need a key to the game for game dedicated transactions. So  there will be some redundant fields anyway. Otherwise I need to have separate GameTransactions, CommissionTransactions, DepositTransactions and withdrawal transactions fields. Which is obviously wrong. Would be nice to hear some hidden drawback from someone who has previously experienced such problems.

Comment: It's not necessarily WRONG it's just going to be harder to maintain.

Comment: But imagine the usecase where I need to show to the user his transaction history order by date. So I need to query all four tables and then mix results together. Sounds like something really wrong to me. Or I need to have a GenericTransactions table with references to tables with particular transaction types. So for each transaction I will have 2 records. Sounds wrong to me as well.

Comment: You don't need to mix the tables, you just need to make a view that `UNION`s all the other tables together.

Comment: @cosmolev Look into the supertype-subtype pattern. The `GenericTransactions` table would be the supertype, and you could put all common columns in it, so that for many queries you wouldn't need to join to the other tables (except when dealing with the columns that are specific to each transaction type). Basically, you convert `NULL` values in columns to the absence of rows in another table. The other, subtype, tables share the same ID as its supertype ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any application where you are tracking money changing hands, you should always use a **Double Entry Accounting** system.  Double entry accounting has been the standard for tracking money for over 500 years.  There is no good reason to use any other method.

This entails a `TRANSACTION` table and a `TRANSACTION_DETAIL` table.  The transaction table has one record per transaction that includes header information, like the date, the total amount, any categorization attributes or relationships, etc.

The transaction detail has two or more records per transaction.  These records break down where the money comes from and goes to.  In your case, you might have three records per transaction.  One shows the money coming in from the payment service.  The other two show the money going out to a commission account and to an income account.

Comment: Thx, Joel! That's exactly where I arrived after reading bunch of articles and examples.